# Auto avatar change and now not able to set it again

Tags: support, moderation, avatar

Some days ago one of the Mods removed my [e-mail](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3655051#3655051) from here and set my avatar as default. I am looking for a strong reason why it happened. If I did anything wrong please let me know. Also, it seems I can't further change my avatar. Why is that? Is that a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: are you asking why it was changed or why you can't change it more?

Comment: Both things happened with me, why it changed and now why I can't.

Comment: I edited the question to better reflect what I think you were trying to ask. Please make further adjustments as necessary.

Comment: **NOTE It has been determined that this user removed his (or her) *own* e-mail address on March 2 and then reinstated it on March 5 after posting this question. This question was asked presumably to troll. I'm closing and locking it.**

Answer (score 6):

I don't know who changed it or why. But the e-mail address formerly associated with that account has a current (and I assume then-) [gravatar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3691527#3691527) that would I think be viewed by many on a Jewish Life & Learning site as highly offensive, so I don't blame him.

I have no idea why you can't change it.

Comment: To show that it really is "many on J.SE" please upvote if you agree with msh210's assessment.

Comment: Because you don't want to see that pic again and also that I set any other one too, that's why you removed my e-mail id from here. which is creating problem to me to set same and any other avatar to my profile pic.